# How to reverse a dictionary in python and create a list out of the duplicate keys value

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by

I gave myself a task today, just trying to figure out the exercise below in Python:

```
# given the dictionary below

dic = {
  "jane": "doe",
  "remy": "ma",
  "haaland": "buuk",
  "adam": "doe",
}

new_dict = {}

for x, y in dic.items():
  if y not in new_dict.keys(): 
    new_dict[y] = x
  else:
    new_dict[y] = [x]

print("results: ", new_dict)

# results:  {'doe': ['adam'], 'ma': 'remy', 'buuk': 'haaland'}
```

How can I rather achieve the following result?

```
results: {'doe': ['jane', 'adam'], 'ma': 'remy', 'buuk': 'haaland'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in sorted(dic.items()):
    res[val].append(key)
```

The same can be done with vanilla dictionary:

```py
res = {}
for i, v in d_input.items():
    res[v] = [i] if v not in res.keys() else res[v] + [i]
```

A neat solution using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(dic).reset_index().groupby(0).agg(list).to_dict()['index']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse_dict(d):
    inv = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v in inv:
            inv[v].append(k)
        else:
            inv[v] = [k]
    return inv

dic = {
  "jane": "doe",
  "remy": "ma",
  "haaland": "buuk",
  "adam": "doe",
}

print(reverse_dict(dic))
```